# File attachment in MVC with Ajax post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in a MVC application. I have a file upload control in my page. 
I will attach only only file at a time by using file upload control. I will show the file name in a grid with delete option.

Those files are needs to be saved when I am clicking the save button (but save button posts data through Ajax call).

Please suggest me a approach.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you asking a question? Any relevant code you would like to share? Or are you expecting someone to build this out for you for free?

Comment: Which fileupload plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi Sadaquat, I am not using any specific plugin, Please suggest me a plug in which suits for Asp.net MVC

Answer (score 3):

There are thousands of plugins avaiblable for fileupload and you can also use HTML5 based solutions.But since you have not specified which plugin are you using so I have just provided you  a complete way to upload a file and save it.

```
<form id="myForm" action="@Url.Action('files', 'controllername')" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
</form>

$("#fileUpload").change(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit();  // meaning whenever you select the file and press OK/Open, form will be submitted.
});


public ActionResult files()
{
     if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
     {
         var file = Request.Files[0];

         if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
         {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
         }
     }

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

Let me know if you are facing any issue in this solution.

Comment: Hi Sadaquat, Thanks for your reply. I will add more number of files and will show the name of the file in a table whatever added. All the files needs to be uploaded when I click final save button. also if I removed a file from the table it should not get upload to server